# AsyncCallback of BackgroundWorker Webservice reference Function

Tags: vb.net, web-services, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build a new class from where I can call functions with a background worker from a web service in a windows Phone 8.1 silverlight app.

calling page

```
LoginPage.xaml.vb
Partial Public Class LoginPage
Private sub Logon()        
        WebServiceHelper.a(WebServiceHelper.Functions.Logon)
        LoginFinish()        
End Sub
End Class
```

WebserviceHelper

```
WebServiceHelper.vb
Public Class WebServiceHelper

Public Shared Sub a(ByVal _Task As Functions)
    If _Task = Functions.Logon Then
        _Service.BeginLogonWindowsPhone(usr, pass, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ResultBackGroundTask), result)    
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ResultBackGroundTask(ByVal result As Object) 
    If _Task = Functions.Logon Then
        ResultObject = result
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is when I call webservice.a() the AsyncCallback ResultBackGroundTask doesn’t fire in time. Instead LoginFinish is called resulting in an error because the resultobject isn’t initialized yet.

I've tried:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync(_Service.BeginLogonWindowsPhone, ResultBackGroundTask, usr, pass, Nothing)
```

But I get an error:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'asyncState' of
'Public Function BeginLogonWindowsPhone(userName As String, password As String, callback As System.AsyncCallback, asyncState As Object) As System.IAsyncResult'.
```

The function I try to call is:

```
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern:=true, Action:="http://test.com/LogonWindowsPhone", ReplyAction:="*"),  _
     System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults:=true)>  _
Function BeginLogonWindowsPhone(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal callback As System.AsyncCallback, ByVal asyncState As Object) As System.IAsyncResult
```

This function is automatically generated in the webservice reference.

I use the Webservice to connect with the clients database, for security reasons.

Comment: You seem to have accidentally a few words there. Could you go through and make sure nothing major is missing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".